# Missing value on UI after deserialization using XamlReader.Load

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

A few short explanations before final question.
I have to clone different UserControls and Panels in my WPF app. I decided to use next approach:

```
xamlString = XamlWriter.Save(control.Content);
stringReader = new StringReader(xamlString);
xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
restoredVisual = (Visual)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

Also I have next class:

```
public class UnitLabel : Label
{
    public string  Unit
    {
        get { return (string )GetValue(UnitProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UnitProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UnitProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Unit", typeof(string), typeof(UnitLabel), new PropertyMetadata(""));
} 
And template for this class
<ControlTemplate x:Key="template" TargetType="local:UnitLabel">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ContentPresenter />
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Unit}" />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Question: Unit string is not visible after deserialization but property Unit has correct value. Do you have any ideas how to fix the issue?

[image: UI before serialization]

[image: UI after deserialization]

I have found the reason and understood that my question is really stupid. Controls lose thier style and templates after deserialization. I can set style and it solves my problem.

Comment: `XamlWriter.Save(control.Content)` serializes the Content of a Control, not the Control itself.

Comment: A more usual approach would be to copy, serialise (or just save to a database) the data from a viewmodel. Then datatemplate that data into ui. Have you considered this approach?

Comment: @Andy, actually, I have another purpose. Different control in the app must be exported to XPS. They have dark baground and light foreground but xps version must have white background and black foreground. This is a reason why I did all these manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Controls lose their styles and templates after deserialization. I can set style and it solves my problem.